# Is the 'Quick Exit' feature commonly applied to websites with sensitive information?

Tags: user-behavior, design-patterns

A developer pointed out this feature that was implemented on a website that I thought really understood the user experience at a high level, and showed that catering for the user experience doesn't just involve the content of the website, but also the behaviour of the user while using the website.

The example comes from a website called [Thorne Harbour Health](https://thorneharbour.org/), and as you can see it has provided a 'Quick Exit' button that when clicked on, takes the user to a website that doesn't contain sensitive information (in this case the Bureau of Meteorology).

I am curious to know if there are other examples like this and if this is a common enough design pattern that reminds me very much of the same feature that used to be available for some desktop applications as well.

[image]

Comment: I have never seen this before. I am not sure that the example shown is accessible, as the escape key is already used for other purposes, such as exiting something (modals and menus) and in screen readers.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't know about this, but after a "quick" search I found it to be a very common feature for increasing Internet security as explained in [infoxchange.org](https://www.infoxchange.org/au/news/2018/05/how-increase-internet-safety-quick-exit-button)

> The quick exit button give users the ability to leave the site quickly, if needed, and act as a prompt that the website contains sensitive information.

---

Quick button definition and use at [techsafety.org](https://www.techsafety.org/exit-from-this-website-quickly/)

> Many websites that have information about domestic violence, sexual assault, or stalking have a “quick escape” or “leave this website” button at the top of their webpages. Some websites have a pop-up message to let you know that you should leave that website if your device is being monitored. These buttons or messages are there to allow someone to quickly leave the website if she or he is concerned that it could be an issue should someone know that they are seeking this kind of information.

> This button is helpful only if someone is watching over your shoulder or enters a room and you need to quickly switch to another website. It will not prevent the other person from going through your browser history or from knowing you were on that website if they are monitoring your device or internet activity remotely.

---

It would be great if there was a design with a standardized icon or shape so that it exists as a common utility and avoid all kinds of explanation.

Comment: +1 nice explanation and reference!